# Error setting data-validation-req-params using formvalidator platform

Tags: jquery, jquery-form-validator

I'm getting this error when I try to set multiple parameters

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data while reading object contents at
>   line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

I'm following the instructions in the [formvalidator.net](http://www.formvalidator.net/#security-validators_backend). I'm using jquery-2.2.2. Here's my code

```html
<?php
    $json = json_encode(array('user'=>$user->get('ID')));
?>
<p>
    <strong>E-mail:</strong>
    <input type="email" name="check-email" data-validation="server" data-validation-url="/validate-form-input.php" data-validation-param-name="email" data-validation-req-params="<?php echo $json ?>" />
</p>
```

The error:

[image]

Thank you so much in advance for answering!

Comment: I accidentally hit the enterbutton. I already edited it.

Comment: Ok. Just FYI It's better for us (and a lot easier for you) to just copy+paste your code in to the question, instead of taking a screenshot and cropping it. I've updated that for you.

Comment: Thank you for doing that, i'm havving a hard time to paste it so i just took a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Change the double quote to single quote.
data-validation-req-params="" to data-validation-req-params=''

reference: https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator/issues/453